# How/when to use json?

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-mvc-3

So, I know the definition of json, I know its a lightweight data format.

As I am not an expert on this subject I would like to know, when can I use JSON, in which scenarios or applications?  How to do it in c#?

I suppose I would Use Json only in applications where I intend to use ajax?

I use Json to call web service methods only so that I can use javascript to show the results without a postback?

Is JSON something to be used only in web forms applications? asp.net mvc applications? silverlight? winforms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you ask too many questions. My personal view on JSON:

1) JSON is a good tool if you need to deal with AJAX (as Sietse pointed out it should be called AJAJ in this case) and webservices

2) JSON is a good tool if you generally need to communicate between different platforms. I used it for communication between PHP and C# program because JSON is implemented in so many languages it is natural to use it and avoid creating custom communication procotol.

Comment: AJAX with JSON is called AJAJ. Since that X at the end means 'XML'. Just for info :)

Comment: @Sietse - Are you sure? I thought Xml referred to the use of XmlHttpRequest object? Seems like AJAJ would be an abbreviation for Asynchronous Javascript And Javascript which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. I googled it now, and that X/J doesn's have anything to do with the request-method.

Answer (score 3):

[JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) can be useful whenever you want to pass data between programs written in two different languages. It's often used in AJAX scenarios, like in your example - a Javascript client receiving data from a server written in C#. But it can be useful in any other situation where your data has to cross a language barrier.

Other alternatives to JSON are [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), etc...

JSON is popular because it can transfer data reliably in a well-defined format (unlike CSV) and is also easily human readable (unlike SOAP).

Comment: any idea why would I choose JSON instead of SOAP when using web services?  I am very used to use SOAP btw

Comment: @Luis - if you're used to Xml with SOAP and none of your endpoints in javascript then go ahead and continue using it. If one of your endpoints IS js however, it will probably be less work to use json.

Comment: I never heard about the concept of a endpoint in javascript, usually y webservices are ASMX or SVC in .NET, Can we create webservices in javascrip? I had no idea about it.

Comment: @Luis: When people say [Web Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) that usually implies SOAP. You *can* use JSON of course, but then it's not what many people would consider to be a valid web service.

Comment: @Luis you're making it too complex, any time that you're communicating between two things each of them is an endpoint. It's a general term, I do not mean to imply any particular technology.

Comment: I read another answer on SO about how to serialize a web service method response in JSON format, normally WCF would serialize in XML, so at the end its a different way to serialize data through the wire? Doing this I suppose the message is smaller and then the performance is better than with the XMLSerializer?

Comment: @Luis Yes, that is correct, the message is smaller, but there are two other advantages. 1) It's significantly more readable than Xml and 2) JSON is a subset of javascript, so for the browser to de-serialize a message it doesn't have to parse Xml, it just executes the json (there's a couple other steps for security, but its basically just that).

Comment: @Luis Oh and of course that at this point more tools support json than xml. jQuery for example will automatically deserialize json requests so you don't have to do it manually - which with xml is a huge pain.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally used for communicating via ajax. It is also used frequently to communicate with document databases such as MongoDB and RavenDB. It is occasionally used to communicate between  applications in general though you lose much of the point once one of the endpoints is no longer javascript. Really any time when you need simple human-readable serialization, JSON is a viable option - I have serialized object hierarchies to JSON and stored them in a single db column before (though only do this if your requirements support it).

Asp Mvc comes with a built in Json serializer but the most popular is probably the excellent [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com) project which is available via nuget.